# Mobile printing PT200 tru Bluetooth opened in web app

Tags: mobile, printing, bluetooth, portability, point-of-sale

I develop a pos system develop in phi. My server is using pc. The system develop for online access. Now the system acces through android phone by typing url of website. On that website opened in mobile phone, I want to print to PT200 printer or GOOJPRT BLUETOOTH connection. Anyone has any idea how to print directly code in php.

I am using mike24 found in GitHub but no luck